# Django: display object's another field from template tag?

Tags: django

I have objects in my database, each object has two values(fields): 'id' and 'name'.

I want to request my model from template tags to display another field of the object, when first one is given.

Example.

```
Model: Fruits

Objects:

Name:Banana ID:1
Name:Apple ID:2
Name:Orange ID:3
```

How do I make a request from my template tag to ask something like: `'display name of the object with ID=1'` or `'display ID of the object named Orange'`?

Comment: template tags do not request anything, they show only what you pass in context in view

Comment: Go through the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/). It might take you a day or two, but it would be worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've read through the documentation and figured out how to complete the task. I had to use [Custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).

This is how. We need to create a folder **'templatetags'** in django app's directory (*myapp/templatetags/*) and two files there: **'__init__.py'** (which is empty) and **'mytags.py'** (that is where we create a custom template tag).

In this example objects have 2 fields: *'id'* and *'name'*. Objects are stored in a model named *'Fruits'*.

*mytags.py*:

```
from myapp.models import Fruits

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_fruits_name(fruits, id):
    fruits = Fruits.objects.get(id=id) # get the object with given id, the id is passed from template.html through custom template tag
    return fruits.name # return the object's name
```

*template.html*:

```
{% load mytags %} # loads mytags.py with our custom template tag
{{ fruits|get_fruits_name:1 }} # displays the name of a fruit with id '1' (in this case, 'Banana')
```

Answer (score 0):

Dos here: [A shortcut: get_object_or_404()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-get-object-or-404).I made some modifications to make it easier to understand.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

from .models import Question
# ...
def detail(request, question_id):
    # get your object here
    question = Question.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})
```

And in templetes

```
{% for qu in question %}
  <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: In your answer you demonstrate how to display all the objects through loop in template tag. I was trying to complete another task: display a specific object's field (that is matching other field passed from template tag). E.g. "display object's name with id '1'" (note that 'id' should be a variable, not hardcoded in views.py). Anyway, I've researched documentation and answered my question. Thanks for help. :)

Comment: @Albert Congratulation !